# Windows 10 file explorer address bar showing previous folder name

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have a folder on my desktop, I renamed this folder to something else. In desktop it shows the folder with the new name but when I open the folder it is showing the previous folder name in address bar. what can cause this problem?

Comment: What language are you using in Windows?

Comment: English (United States)

Comment: Try refreshing the file explorer by clicking the button beside search bar.

Comment: @WasifHasan that does not work.

Comment: Create a new folder and repeat everything . Check if problem persistents . Also attach a screenshot (will be helpful a sort of!!!)

Comment: @Madhubala new folders are ok. only this folder have problem.

Comment: Which name shows in PowerShell/Cmd?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have made a short cut, not a copy of the folder. Renaming the shortcut does not affect the real folder name.
You can recognize a short cut by the arrow in the lower left corner of the folder icon.

Comment: It is not a shortcut. Its a folder you can see in cmd.